# Send post id through ajax and get the post content back

Tags: posts, functions, templates, ajax

First of all i want to say that I am a WordPress beginner :). I am trying to get a post content in a modal by using ajax. So i send the id through ajax, but i cannot execute the php code anywhere on my theme because of a fatal error.

jQuery code looks like this:

```
$('.post-box').click(function(){
  var id_post = $(this).attr('id');

  $.ajax({
    url: "path-to-my-theme/ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        'post_id': id_post
    },
    success:function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
  });
});
```

This is the php code inside the file ajax.php that i have created in my theme root

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST["post_id"]) && isset($_POST["post_id"]) != '') {       
      $post_id = $_POST["post_id"];

      // wordpress post loop here with the post id
    }
?>
```

The problem is that any WP function i get there, it gets a Fatal error: Call to undefined function. How can i connect this file to the WP functions, what should i do in this situation in order for this to work ?

Comment: You should look into [WordPresses built in Ajax Functionality](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/) - [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) which allows you to set a callback function in your JS -> `'action': 'functoin_name'` then you can specific you ajax actions via:  `wp_ajax_function_name` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_function_name`. Then you can add your function into your themes `functions.php` for ease.